# How to move all the indicators from bottom panel to top panel in GNOME 3.2.0?

Tags: gnome, indicator, panel

I want to work with GNOME 3.x instead of Unity 3D. I find it more comfortable but the only thing missing for me is that all of the indicators are now located at the bottom panel in contrast to Unity which locate them in the top panel.

How can I move them to the top panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question in the right way, With [this great extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/99/evial-status-icon-forerver/)

Comment: OK, i got stuck in the beginning but after a few tries i've succeeded :)
pay attention when you get into the link above, there is a button at the upper left side of the page, just turn it on.
after you turn it on, the extension will be installed in your computer. edit the extension.js file, there is an array called "notification", just add the indicator names as they seemed at the bottom panel.
at the beginning I've downloaded another extension which is similar but didn't work - [link](https://github.com/brianhsu/EvilStatusIconForever), you can download a zip file but it didn't work for me.

Comment: This extension does not work anymore in 2016.

Comment: It does not surprise me that an answer 4 years and 16 versions of Gnome old does not work anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the TopIcons Gnome extension:

1. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/
2. Allow the website integration
3. Flip the switch to "On"
4. Accept
5. Immediately, the indicators move to the top bar, and the left-bottom bar disappears

[image: Topbar]